# Dedekind complete quotients of Riesz spaces

Tags: lattice-theory, vector-spaces

Suppose that $E$ is a Dedekind complete Riesz space and let $J$ be an order ideal of $E$. Then one can form a quotient Riesz space $E/J$. I am interested which  properties $J$ needs to possess so that $E/J$ will be Dedekind complete as well.

I am certain in at least one case that this will happen. If $J$ is a band in $E$, then $J$ is a projection band which implies that $E/J$ is order isomorphic to the Dedekind complete Riesz space $E^d.$

I am not aware on any other situations. Any other situation that will force $E/J$ to be Dedekind complete is appreciated.